# Simple flag based comparison in Linux

Tags: linux

I am trying to run a simple script to check for a flag and then check for additional conditions. The following always echoes "Run Script.." irrespective of the value of the flag:

```
FLAG_Control=false
if [ $FLAG_Control ] && [ -d /path/to/dir ];then
    echo "Run script.."
fi
```

while this works as expected:

```
FLAG_Control=false
if [ $FLAG_Control = true ] && [ -d /path/to/dir ];then
    echo "Run script.."
fi
```

Does this mean that I have to do an explicit comparison? Am I doing something wrong in the first one?

Comment: That is because the variable `FLAG_Control=false` is set an yields always to true. The `false` there is misleading. It is not a boolean value as you are used to other programming languages. `false`  is just a value that initializes `FLAG_Control` variable and sets it to true.  `FLAG_Control=` which is not initialized yields to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `if $FLAG_Control && [ -d /path/to/dir ]; ...`. Note that the brackets are not part of the syntax for `if`; in this case you want `$FLAG_Control` to be interpreted as a command (`true` or `false`), and that will play well with `&&` and the other `[ ... ]` clause. (This assumes that your variable is always set to either `true` or `false`.)

The reason your initial test doesn't do what you meant can be seen in the documentation for `test` (aka `[`):

```
-n STRING
       the length of STRING is nonzero

STRING equivalent to -n STRING
```

Since `false` doesn't have any special meaning here, it's simply seen as a non-empty string, which is interpreted as a true value.

Comment: Thanks... the script works with the method you suggested! Now I understand why my first one did not work.

Comment: I doubt that techiebong meant to execute `false` as a command; I suspect that he thought he was just evaluating it as a Boolean value. But this is one way to get the script to work.

Comment: You say, “This assumes that your variable is always set to either true or false.” That statement deserves more attention. If this script will ever be run by anybody other than the author, you have to really make sure that `$FLAG_Control` is never set to anything other than `true` or `false`; i.e., that the user cannot manipulate the script into setting it to something like `rm *` (i.e., this becomes a security / input validation issue). I suggest that string comparison is safer.

Answer (score 0):

I have been learning bash scripting over the past few months.  What I have learned is that there are no boolean variables in bash.  However, that isn't to say there aren't any boolean values.

If/then looks for 1 or 0.  Now.... here's the caveat:  0 is true and everything else is false.  For example, when you check to see if a directly exists the result comes back as 0 not 1.

If you get any sort of error code from the function you call, you can trap for that error.

So, try this instead:

```
FLAG_Control=1
if [ $FLAG_Control ] && [ -d /path/to/dir ];then
   echo "Run script.."
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. That helps! I also found this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953646/how-to-declare-and-use-boolean-variables-in-shell-script) very helpful.

Comment: That's a good link with some good explanations, but it does get confusing.   Bash is strange environment where syntaxes can run the gamut.  My latest thing now is to always explicitly reference my variables with braces {}.  Ex:  `${foo}`  While `$foo` works just fine, I had a printf formatting issue that took forever to solve.  The braces solved it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at, @Allan; `[ 0 ]` and `[ 1 ]` are both true, so setting the variable to `0` would still lead to surprising results.

Comment: Allan: While enclosing variables in braces is often important, it is not equivalent to quoting them, which is even more important. E.g., `"$foo"` and `${foo}` are both better than `$foo`, but `"${foo}"` may be even better than either. … … @dhag: I suspect that Allan is thinking that the options are `FLAG_Control=1` and `FLAG_Control=` (i.e., null); but, of course, he would need to say `[ "$FLAG_Control" ]` to make that work.

Comment: @dhag:  Setting my flags the way I have described has worked thus far.  If I am doing it wrong then my bad.

Answer (score -1):

The nearest thing to a *true* value for a shell a variable is a *set* value. There are some native parameter properties that depend on it as well. For example:

```
FLAG=
[ -d "${FLAG:+$HOME}" ] || ! echo \
either \$HOME is not a directory or \$FLAG is null or unset
```

Above `$FLAG` conditionally expands to the value of `$HOME` only if it is set and not null. There are several variations on this, but the overall gist is that the parameter's value is not always quite so important as whether the parameter *has* a value. Setting `FLAG` to any value at all above would result in a true return from `test` rather than a failure.